# How to rotate Optic Form

Tags: c#, gdi+, picturebox, image-rotation, perspective

I am scanning optical forms as jpg or png. Some are leaning to the left and right while scanning. I want to fix the tilts by checking the small coordinate points on the optical form. How can I fix it with windows form (C#)? Thanks indeed.

Comment: Can you please provide some more background? What do you have so far?

Comment: I sent the photo of optical form that I work on https://i.hizliresim.com/8NoJPr.png. The problem is that, the optical form leans right or left when scanning. I want to rotate the paper to its original position. Is there any  technologies, framework or sample work to help me with it? That's the problem I want to solve. Thank indeed.

Comment: You might have to scan across each line of the image, recording the left most pixel above a specific darkness threshold.  Once you have that, those should all be in a line (with some slight error from analog scanning).  You can calculate the angle of that line and use it to redraw the image with rotation to correct it.  There is nothing build in to .net to do this, though there are some decent 3rd party image intelligence libraries that may be able to help.

Comment: Your explanations were very useful. Thank you very much. Take care.